# ArCore Sceneform, calculate angle between 3 anchor nodes A -> B -> C in degrees

Tags: math, arcore, sceneform

I have 3 anchor nodes lets say A, B, C.
A is connected to B and B is connected to C, forming an "open triangle".

I need to calculate the angle formed by both the lines at point B.

How is that possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either arcore or sceneform, but if they provide something called `atan2` and you know the coordinates of the three nodes, then atan2 should work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to achieve this using these set of instructions :

```
val abLen = Vector3.subtract(pointNodes[0].worldPosition, pointNodes[1].worldPosition).length()
val bcLen = Vector3.subtract(pointNodes[1].worldPosition, pointNodes[2].worldPosition).length()

val prodLen = abLen * bcLen
val dotProd = Vector3.dot(Vector3.subtract(pointNodes[0].worldPosition, pointNodes[1].worldPosition), Vector3.subtract(pointNodes[2].worldPosition, pointNodes[1].worldPosition))
val dp = dotProd / prodLen
val angleInDegrees = acos(dp.toDouble()) * 180 / Math.PI
```

Where pointNodes is an array of anchor nodes containing 3 anchor nodes A at 0, B at 1 and C at 2.